# Building Flutter sqflite ios app using codemagic.io

Tags: flutter, sqflite, codemagic

My flutter app works fine on android emulator and I am using codemagic.io to build the ios version since I am on windows.

However, when trying to build the ios app, the site is showing the following error and I think it has to do with sqflite.

As far as I understand, I guess, I have to change the minimum targeted ios version but actually I don't know how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Xcode's output:

```
↳
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabaseQueue.m:101:9: warning: 'dispatch_queue_set_specific' **is only available on iOS 5.0 or newer** [-Wunguarded-availability]
            dispatch_queue_set_specific(_queue, kDispatchQueueSpecificKey, (__bridge void *)self, NULL);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabaseQueue.h:9:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode-11.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Dispatch' imported from /Applications/Xcode-11.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:20:
    /Applications/Xcode-11.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/queue.h:1498:1: **note: 'dispatch_queue_set_specific' has been marked as being introduced in iOS 5.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS 4.3.0**
    dispatch_queue_set_specific(dispatch_queue_t queue, const void *key,
    ^
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabaseQueue.m:101:9: note: enclose 'dispatch_queue_set_specific' in an @available check to silence this warning
            dispatch_queue_set_specific(_queue, kDispatchQueueSpecificKey, (__bridge void *)self, NULL);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/FMDB/src/fmdb/FMDatabaseQueue.m:184:54: warning: 'dispatch_get_specific' **is only available on iOS 5.0 or newer** [-Wunguarded-availability]
        FMDatabaseQueue *currentSyncQueue = (__bridge id)dispatch_get_specific(kDispatchQueueSpecificKey);
```

Comment: Hi @Jack, check Xcode guides how to change minimum targeted iOS version, and Codemagic has free VNC access to macOS computer to update your Xcode settings

Comment: @MikhailTokarev I already changed the deployment target to ios 11.0 but still I am getting this error from Codemagic  'dispatch_queue_set_specific' has been marked as being introduced in iOS 5.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS 4.3.0

Comment: warning: 'sqlite3_wal_checkpoint_v2' is only available on iOS 5.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
        int err = sqlite3_wal_checkpoint_v2(_db, dbName, checkpointMode, logFrameCount, checkpointCount);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled flutter and that solved the problem